# Correct way to use class in Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am newbie to Ruby - I have a SOAP Web service I need to hit that takes any number of car details- I haven't decided yet to how the user inputs the details- may be from screen - may be from a file they upload, etc.

I am trying to design this so it is easy to plug in whatever the input method will be.

In order to build up the Request to the webservice for Testing I do the following:

```
car = { 'abc:Id' => '1', 'abc:ModelNumber' => 18, 'abc:ES' => 3.0, 'abc:ND' => 4 }

cars= {'mun:Car' => [car] }
```

So currently I have created a cars class as below - Note ES is Engine Size and ND is number of doors - also ModelNumber and Id are written as the request expects - and the abc is the specific namespace which I need to add to the parameter.

```
class Car
    def initialize(id, modelNumber, engineSize, noDoors)
      # Instance variables
      @id = id
      @modelNumber = modelNumber
      @engineSize = engineSize
      @noDoors = noDoors
end
```

The values I need to change then are the Id, model number, etc.  My question is how can I create a new Coordinate class and then create a for loop say and build up a request with say 10 Cars keeping the format of the request as I need it.  So my XML request at the min looks like:

```
<abc:Coordinate>
  <abc:Id>1</mun:Id>
  <abc:ModelNumber>18</abc:ModelNumber>
  <abc:NS>3.0</abc:X>
  <abc:ND>4</abc:Y>
</abc:Coordinate>
```

However in reality I want to pass in multiple number or cars so a Sample part of the XMl would look like:

```
<abc:Coordinate>
  <abc:Id>1</mun:Id>
  <abc:ModelNumber>18</abc:ModelNumber>
  <abc:NS>3.0</abc:X>
  <abc:ND>4</abc:Y>
</abc:Coordinate>
<abc:Coordinate>
  <abc:Id>2</mun:Id>
  <abc:ModelNumber>19</abc:ModelNumber>
  <abc:NS>3.5</abc:X>
  <abc:ND>3</abc:Y>
</abc:Coordinate>
<abc:Coordinate>
  <abc:Id>3</mun:Id>
  <abc:ModelNumber>20</abc:ModelNumber>
  <abc:NS>4.0</abc:X>
  <abc:ND>5</abc:Y>
</abc:Coordinate>
```

What is the best way in Ruby to use the Car class I created but build up the XML as required?

Comment: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/ruby/ruby_classes.htm

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you're looking for. It sounds like you ultimately need an array of `Car` objects. Also, given your description, `...how can I create a new Coordinate class and then create a for loop say and build up a request with say 10 Cars...` it seems like you've already got the correct idea down, so what part are you having difficulty with?

Comment: @Paul Richter - its how to I create the abc:Id, abc:ModelNumber part of the request as if I just did car_a = new Car("1", 18, 3.0, 4) them parts of the requst wont be set.